# How to synchronize my smartphone to my Google account?

Tags: sync, google-account

Everytime I take photos with my smartphone, I want to synchronize it automatically to my Google account. How to achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope the following instructions help ...

- Open the 'Photos' app on your device
- click on the 3 horizontal lines on the top left part of the screen(just before the search field)
- Access 'Settings' option from the drawn up menu panel
- You have the 'Backup & Sync' option at the beginning of the list.
- Select that option and setup your backup account.

You have various other options ... you might want to look into each of those and choose one's that you require and you have setup your device to automatically sync photos.

Play around and look into the various settings ... it will reveal options you never thought existed ... improves the quality of your usage to the maximum.